# TTntComboBox blank first row

Tags: combobox, modal-dialog, c++builder

I have a TTntComboBox and I'm setting the itemindex to a positive value before showing the modal dialog (to which the combo box belongs), but the first time, the combo box shows an empty item.

If I close the dialog and re-open it, it shows the desired item.

The itemindex is not -1 before showing the dialog for the first time and the combobox style is csDropDownList.

Edit->

Putting in key snippets of code
In the main function - form initialized as

```
     Application->CreateForm(__classid(TChildDialog), &ChildDialog);
```

in WinMain

The parent dialog has a listbox and edit, add and delete button to edit, add, delete the entries of the listbox. When any of the button is clicked, the data of the entry is shown by the form in question (I'll call it ChildDialog)
.
The action associated with edit button is as follows(parent form)

```
if (ListBox->ItemIndex >= 0) {
   TTntListItem *Item = ListBox->Items->Item[ListBox->ItemIndex];
   ChildDialog->SetData(Item->Data);
   if (ChildDialog->ShowModal() == mrOk) {
      delete Item->Data;
      TData *NewData = ChildDialog->GenerateData();
      PopulateData(Item, NewData);
   }
}


void __fastcall ParentForm::PopulateData(TTntListItem *Item, TData *Data) {
   Item->Data = Data;
   Item->SubItems->Clear();
   Item->SubItems->Add(functionUsingSomeDatastruct(Data));
}
```

And the SetData of ChildDialog (form in question)- which has editbox, combobox is as follows

```
void __fastcall TChildDialog::SetData(TData *Data)
 for (int i = 0; i < someDataStructLength(); i++) {
    if (!strcmp(someDataStruct(i)->String, Data))      {
     combobox->ItemIndex = i;
     break;
   }
}
EditBox->Text = SomeData.String2;
```

The ctor of child dialog is defined as

```
 __fastcall ChildDialog::ChildDialog(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
  {
    combobox->Items->Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < datacount(); i++) {
      combobox->Items->Add(someDataStruct(i)->Sring);
    }
    combobox->ItemIndex = 0;
   }
```

Comment: How do you show the form? Do you create new instance of it every time, or do you reuse the same instance? When do you set the item index?

Comment: I reuse the same instance. I show the form as  "if (Dialog->ShowModal() == mrOk) { <save edits> }". Just before showing the dialog, I set the item index to a positive value.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with what you describe, so I'm going to posit that there is something wrong with a part of the code that you don't describe. This could be a lot of things, but you might get an answer pretty quickly if you post some source code. In lieu of this, I'm going make guess that you are creating two (or more) instances of your dialog form. The one that you set the ItemIndex in is not the same one as you are showing.

Comment: You have some design flaw in your code, but since we don't have access to it, we cannot tell you what it is. One possibility is that you set the item index *before* you populate the list box with items.

Comment: I've added the key snippets of code. It is commercial code. The code was working fine before I made changes for i18n, I used WideString instead of AnsiString for the editbox, combobox and other static data on the form.There are couple of more changes on how I fetch some underlying data structures, but no changes to the UI elements

Comment: changed subject to avoid confusion

Comment: Can somebody please answer it instead of marking it down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. I am using gettext for localization.

In FormShow - I was calling TranslateComponent as

```
 ChildDialog::FormShow() {
    TranslateComponent(this);
 }
```

which was resetting Combobox's ItemIndex.

Now moved it to ctor.

Comment: +1 for finding and posting the answer here even after all the negative and close votes.

Comment: @dips, you can mark your own answer as correct (click the checkmark.)  That'll probably earn you some badge or other too :)